# mixing table of contents and header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, document-classes

For some reasons, my `table of contents` gets mixed with the `header` in all the pages of an article and I am wondering about the causes.

Thanks in advance for your explanation and best,

```
\documentclass[a4paper12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{lscape}

 \usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{threeparttable}

 %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{framed}
  %\usepackage{fourier}

 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth, 
 height=20.0mm]bbbb.png}}

 \title{\hspace{2ex}doc first title  \newline \newline 2nd part of title}
 \author{\hspace{9ex} auteur
 \newline\url{http://url}}
  \date{date}

  % Definition of \maketitle
  \makeatletter         
  \def\@maketitle{
  \raggedright
   \includegraphics[width = 40mm]{f.jpg}\\[8ex]
   \begin{center}

 {\Huge \bfseries \sffamily \@title }\\[4ex] 
 {\Large  \@author}\\[4ex] 
 \@date\\[8ex]
 \includegraphics[width = 40mm]{f.jpg}
 \end{center}}
  \makeatother

 \begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This 
\end{abstract}
\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\vspace{2.5cm}

\newpage
\section{Glossary}

\section{sec1}

\end{document}
```

Output: sec1____________________________________________ picture

Comment: Your MWE contains several errors. You didn't load the `graphicx` package but use `\includegraphics`. There is a missing `{`. You use `\url` without loading the correct package. Also in a MWE you should not use files like `f.jpg` but `example-image` or `example-image-b` or the like.

Comment: actually for illustration purposes, i skipped those packages on purposes

Comment: You should not have done that because this way your example is not compilable.

Comment: i've added the packages, fyi

Comment: The issue is that your specified head is too large. It does take up more space than is reserved for it. As a result it gets shifted down into the text area but the text area isn't shifted accordingly. Setup the header's space to be larger with `geometry` and your problem is solved.

Comment: Also now your MWE loads more packages than necessary to recreate the issue :)

Comment: as i take header-related script from a `adhoc` template found online, it would be appreciated to have some tips using `geometry` for adjusting the setup.

Comment: See [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for the documentation of `geometry`. Or take a look at my answer for a minimal solution.

Comment: fine. i saw the example: following the update i can see only on `odd` pages the mix between sections from my tables of contents and the header (picture), whereas on the `even` pages i only see the pictures in the header. the idea was to see the header (picture) in all the pages for consistency purposes.

Comment: See my edit, it sets the left header, too.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thank you so much for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header takes up at least 20mm of vertical space (because of your `\includegraphics` instruction). Change the `headheight` with `geometry` to match at least that space and your problem should be solved. If you alway want the section title on the left header, you should use something like `\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}`. If you want an empty left header on each page use `\fancyhead[L]{}` instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper12pt]{article}

\usepackage[headheight=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth, 
 height=20.0mm]{example-image-b}}
 \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}

 \title{foo}\author{bar}

 \begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This 
\end{abstract}
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Glossary}

\section{sec1}

\end{document}
```

[image]